# Add keyevent to switch ViewPart under IPageLayout

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp

how to assign key for switch focus on different viewpart??

example: (press "SWT.F7" to focus on viewpartA, "SWT.F8" to focus on viewpartB)

```
public class UserPerspective implements IPerspectiveFactory{
    ......
    ......
    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout){
        final IFolderLayout leftPanel = layout.createFolder(......);
        leftPanel.addView(viewpartA.ID);

        final IFolderLayout rightPanel = layout.createFolder(......);
        rightPanel.addView(viewpartB.ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to accept or vote for answers :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following key bindings. Read the documentation for the sequence carefully - it is a little tricky :-)

The `value` attribute below is the ID for your target view.

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
   <key
         commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
         schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
         sequence="F6">
      <parameter
            id="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
            value="com.rcpcompany.so.ed.view">
      </parameter>
   </key>
   <key
         commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
         schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
         sequence="SHIFT+F6">
      <parameter
            id="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
            value="com.rcpcompany.so.ed.view1">
      </parameter>
   </key>
</extension>
```