# Add keyevent to switch ViewPart under IPageLayout? (Part 2)

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp

*Previous question: (Thank you Tonny Madsen to answer me)

[Add keyevent to switch ViewPart under IPageLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062132/add-keyevent-to-switch-viewpart-under-ipagelayout)*

Moreover,

if I have more than one "view1", how can I assign the different short key for both of them??

And is it possible to assign the short key for the "view1" function call?? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have defined your view with `allowMultiple = true`.

To my knowledge, you cannot add a secondary ID to the view ID specified with the `org.eclipse.ui.views.showView` command. You can check yourself in `org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler`.

One possible solution though, is to define your own command and handler. Based on the standard version, it should be pretty easy for you to do.